# WPF MVVM share object between view model and code behind

Tags: wpf, mvvm-light

I am trying to share the following object between my view model and code behind

```
Dictionary<ItemTypeType, Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int,List<ConfigParameter>>>> ItemToConfigParametersValues
```

This object is not used in the XAML. It is used in the code behind for several dynamically generated UI Elements.

What is the MVVM Light way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the ViewModel is typically set as the "DataContext" of the View.  Code-behind is part of the View.

So... just expose the data from your ViewModel.  In your code-behind, you can access it using the [DataContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.datacontext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) property (with appropriate casting).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is what I was thinking of doing. But isn't this a bad thing to do?

Comment: @Nick I think the real question is, what are you trying to do?  Trying to expose something like that seems... unreasonable.

Comment: @NETscape The UI has to let users modify, view, and edit data that is not completely understood until runtime.

Comment: @Nick You can load the data during runtime, into your view model, and display it then. There is no need for code behind in this case if you're following MVVM properly.

Answer (score 0):

I would store the viewmodel in a variable so I didnt need to cast DataContext everytime... In the MainWindow.xaml.cs code behind for example:

```
private MainWindowViewModel _vm;

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    this._vm = new MainWindowViewModel();
    // this._vm.MyProperty = ... (or does the vm instantiate MyProperty?)
    this.DataContext = this._vm;
}    

private void HandleSomeEvent(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var sharedObject = _vm.MyProperty;
}
```